# Fixed position throwing of my headers centering unless I set width of header to 100% why?

Tags: css, stylesheet, sass

Let's say I have a header:

```
header {
     background-color: $main-background-color;
     height: 86px;

            #headerContent {
               background-color: $main-background-color;
               height:86px;
               margin:0px auto 0px auto;
               width: $site-width;
            }
}
```

When a user logs in the header settings are changed to:

```
header {
    background-color: $main-background-color;
    position:fixed; 
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;

        #headerContent {
            position:relative;
            background-color: $main-background-color;
            width: $site-width;
            margin:0px auto 0px auto;
            height:40px;
                img {
                    margin-top:12px;
                }
        }

}
```

What I want to know is why does all my centering mess up if the header width is set to auto? I can only use %. Is this using the browser to determine what 100% is? When I use auto the header seems to disappear and i can only see my headercontent div which is then shifted to the left of the page.

I have it working now but would just like to understand what is going on.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position `fixed` & `absolute` are default take content `width` & `height`. that's why when you define `auto` it's take it's content `width`. It's better to define `left` & `right` instead of `width:100%` for this. Like this:

```
header{
 right:0;
 left:0;
 position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Works the same as %.. thanks. So any children of this head will automatically be fixed too? Is this why my head content stays fixed when I scroll too?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem comes from `position:fixed` on your header. When you make elements fixed they break out of normal page flow and the container will collapse to the size of its content. To test, if you remove the `position:fixed` declaration you should see that you won't need to set width to 100%.